# jQuery - iteration + addClass on array elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, addclass

I have:

```
    $('#a1').addClass('play');
    $('#a3').addClass('play');
    $('#a5').addClass('play');  
    $('#a16').addClass('play');
    $('#b3').addClass('play');
```

So decided it was best to use something like:

```
var doString="m7,m7,a1,b2,c3,p16,o15,n14,d8,e7,g5,i4,l4,n6,o8,n10,m11,k12,i11,i13,k15,l16,f9";
var strArray1 = doString.split(",");
console.log(doString);
console.log(strArray1);

$.each(strArray1, function(i, elem) { 
    console.log(elem); 
    $('#'+elem+').addClass('play'); // not working
});
```

But can't figure the correct parameter to add the class to each element.

How can I do this?

Comment: sorry, I edited out my original question, as I was trying to solve it myself and copied another non working copy. Realised my mistake and edited, still that one wasn't working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.each(strArray1, function(i, val) { 

    // i => index(0,1,..)
    // val => m7,m7,a1,...

    $( '#' + val ).addClass('play'); 
});
```

***OR***

```
$.each(strArray1, function() { 

    // this[0] => m7,m7,a1,...

    $( '#' + this[0] ).addClass('play'); 
});
```

#### After edit (your code)

```
$.each(strArray1, function(i, elem) { 
    console.log(elem); 
    $('#'+elem+').addClass('play'); // not working
});
```

Where `$('#'+elem+')` should be  `$('#'+ elem )`.

#### Here, you've to remove the trailing `+'` from the selector and then its perfect.

Comment: a simple `for` loop would reduce the overhead of the call to `$.each`

Comment: @MrOBrian may be, but this help OP to find the error and correct path.